# Widget function's sharing unwanted properties [kivy]

Tags: python, kivy

I have two widgets, a body and a header. I want to print out 'Header Widget has been pressed' whenever I click on the header. The problem is that if I click on the body (or anywhere in the window), it also returns 'Header Widget has been pressed.'

[image: GUI]

> gui.py

```
class header(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print('Header Widget has been pressed')

class body(Widget):
    pass

class gui(Widget):
    pass
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(body())
        self.add_widget(header())

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.borderless = True
        self.gui = gui()
        return self.gui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

> Main.kv

```
<body>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: 249, 228 -39
            source: "./assets/background.png"

<header>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 228 -39
            size: 249, 39
            source: "./assets/header.png"
```

I made sure that the body doesn't overlap the header in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `on_touch_down()`, `on_touch_move()` and `on_touch_up()` get the touchs on the entire app, and not just in the class we are declaring. So we need to check if the touch is inside the class or not.

First, you are not positioning the `header` widget, only the `Rectangle`, so we have to fix this to be able to get the click correctly:

```
<header>:
    pos: 0, 228 -39
    size: 249, 39
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 228 -39
            size: 249, 39
            source: "./assets/header.png"
```

Now we can check if the touch is inside the widget or not. For this we will use the `collide_point` function to check if the touch colides with our `header`:

```py
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        print('Header Widget has been pressed')
```